# Plotting square function with ggplot2 geom_line?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I use ggplot2's `geom_line` to plot a square function, where x,y coordinates are connected by squares rather than by lines?

Something that looks like:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use `geom_step`:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:10, 
                y = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_step()
```

[image]